# Highlight.js not respecting parent regex of a sub mode

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, highlight, highlight.js

I need to write a lexer which highlights my command-line tool commands properly.

```
$ dvc add file.csv
$ dvc pipeline list
```

So the command starts with `dvc` and it may have one or two subcommands: `add` or `pipeline list` respectively.

Therefore, it should highlight `dvc add` and `dvc pipeline list` in first and second case respectively.

```
contains: [
          {
            begin: /^\s*\$\s(dvc|git) [a-z-]+/,
            returnBegin: true,
            contains: [
              {
                begin: /dvc [a-z-]+ ?/,
                lexemes: '[a-z-]+',
                keywords: {
                  built_in:
                    'dvc'
                },
                contains: [
                  {
                    begin: /\w+(?![\S])/,
                    keywords: {
                      built_in: 'list'
                    }
                  }
                ],
                className: 'strong'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

It matches `dvc pipeline list` even though the parent regex (i.e. `/^\s*\$\s(dvc|git) [a-z-]+/`) should only match till `dvc pipeline`. How is it exactly functioning?

How does `/dvc [a-z-]+ ?/` override it and continues matching the expression?

Please refer to this library docs here: https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html

Comment: Please give a bit more context to that question - link to the highlighter docs for example.

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? This would make it easy to interactively investigate the issue.

Comment: What does `lexemes: '[a-z-]+',` do?

Comment: @ColdCerberus
I think it's there to match keywords. https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#lexemes

Comment: I see. Also, have you confirmed that the `\W` or `\S` does not cause the problem? There have been bugs before regarding these

Comment: @ColdCerberus the `\w` and `\S` in `/\w+(?![\S])/`? Why would that cause a problem? That's intentionally added to match the second sub command which is `list` here.

Comment: What I meant is there were bugs in the past regarding `\W` and `\S`. I didn't mean to say that  your statement `/\w+(?![\S])/` is faulty. It should do as intended, given that there is no bug to how the expression is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Begin only starts a match, it does not limit it.  The first rule matches, then rewinds... then `/dvc [a-z-]+ ?/` is matched which will then start looking for children in `contains` ... so then `/\w+(?![\S])/` is matched (you're still inside your strong rule) so you'd see:

```
<strong>dvc pipeline list</strong>
```

```html
<!-- matches /^\s*\$\s(dvc|git) [a-z-]+/ -->
  <!-- matches /dvc [a-z-]+ ?/ -->
  <strong>
    dvc pipeline   
      <!-- contains matches  /\w+(?![\S])/ --> 
      list
      <!-- no more matches for /\w+(?![\S])/ --> 
      <!-- end fires, back up -->
    <!-- no more matches for /dvc [a-z-]+ ?/-->
    <!-- end fires --> 
  </strong>
  <!-- back up -->
```

If you want to detect a bunch of different patterns I'd suggest different modes for each:

```
{ begin: /dvc add .../, contains: ... }
{ begin: /dvc pipeline .../, contains: ... }
```

Although you may also want to take a look at `starts` vs `contains`.  Writing grammars to express match A, then B, then C can be quite difficult.  The tools are there, but it can be very complex to get right and fraught with peril vs doing something simpler.